# Browser designed for dark mode

Tags: browser, google-chrome-extension, firefox-addon, windows-10, screen

Is there a browser designed for dark mode or night mode. Besides Chrome or Firefox, they both have bugs for this design. Chrome has a flashing white screen on every page load and Firefox is unable to log in to Hotmail. A browser specifically designed for night mode would be ideal for Windows 10 64-bit.

Answer (score 2):

I have Firefox on Windows 10 64-bits, with this add-on [Dark Mode](https://mybrowseraddon.com/dark-mode.html) and almost every web-page is well displayed with a dark smooth that you can customize (with lots of dark colors), and even better it lets sites such as YouTube to display their own dark mode.

[Also I can login to Hotmail with no problems](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7kGC3.png)

[You only have to click on the slim bar to type your username](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zGsMt.png)

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Vivaldi](https://vivaldi.com), which is made for completely customized color schemes. Additionally, if you want to enhance chrome or Vivaldi (which can use Chrome-Addons) you could install [Dark-Reader](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/dark-reader/eimadpbcbfnmbkopoojfekhnkhdbieeh).